# How can I get the URLs in this .cmd-file to open in Internet Explorer instead of Edge if Edge is the default browser?

Tags: url, command, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, shortcut

I have a batch file that should open all websites that our co-workers use daily. It should open them in IE11, since some of our pages do not work on Edge. 
However, if the user has Edge set as their default browser, the pages open up in Edge instead.

I added the full path to iexploer, since this was supposed to open them specifically into IE, however Edge seems to overrule that somehow.

There does not seem to be a difference between these:
C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\"

I also had the issue that each url opened up in a seperate window, or that only the first page opened at all. These were fixed with the ping after the first command line.

The code:

```
@echo off  
start "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" websiteURL  
Ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul  
start "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" websiteURL  
start "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" websiteURL  
start "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" websiteURL  
start "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" websiteURL  
start "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" websiteURL  
start "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" websiteURL
```

These URL's should open in Internet Explorer, since that is also determined in the command lines... Please help :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use a visual basic script like this :

```
site1 = "http://google.com"
site2 = "http://yahoo.com"

Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.Visible = True
oIE.Navigate2 site1
oIE.Navigate2 site2,navOpenInBackgroundTab

Set oIE = Nothing
```

or alternatively you can set a timeout of x seconds between the commands in your batch file ( waiting for the first IE window to open )

Answer (score 0):

If you try to add **IEXPLORE.EXE** after the path than it will open all the links in IE even if any other browser was set as default browser.

```
@echo off  
start "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" IEXPLORE.EXE https://www.microsoft.com  
Ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul  
start "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" IEXPLORE.EXE https://www.microsoft.com  
start "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" IEXPLORE.EXE https://www.microsoft.com
```

But it will open all the links in new IE Window.

If your goal is to open multiple web pages only in single window in IE than you can try to set group policy for that, which user cannot change from IE settings.

To set the group policy you can refer steps below.

(1) Type **gpedit.msc** in Run window to open **Local group policy editor**.

(2) Navigate to location below.

```
Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer\
```

(3) Find the key named as **Disable Changing Home Page Settings**.

(4) Double click on it to configure this setting.

(5) User can click on **Enabled** option to enable this policy.

(6) User can click on **Show** button and add values (site addresses) like below.

[image]

(6) Click on **Apply** button to apply this change and click **OK** to close the configuration window.

If you enable this policy setting, you can specify which default home pages should load as secondary home pages. The user cannot set custom default secondary home pages.

**Notes:** 
(1) If the “Disable Changing Home Page Settings” policy is enabled, the user cannot add secondary home pages.

After applying this policy, Whenever user open IE or click on Home button, It will open these pages.